# Can Tablix Row Total only refer to last X groups?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report in a tablix with 1 to x column groups.  In the totals for each row, is it possible to refer to only say the last 2 groups?  The requirement is to add a column that shows the most recent % change between the last 2 groups.

```
Jan   Feb   Mar   |Total  Recent % Change
5     10    5      20     50%
1     3     6      10     200%
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the technique I learned in this post:  [Creating conditional total rows in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472571/creating-conditional-total-rows-in-ssrs)

Basically, I added another field with the ranking/order of the Groups in descending order (so that the most recent group is #1).

Example of the expression: *(Note that I have custom code to do the divide so that I don't get divide by zero errors.)*

```
=code.divide(sum(iif(fields!Last_ORDER.Value=1,fields!Num_Apps_Submitted.Value,0)),sum(iif(fields!Last_ORDER.Value=2,fields!Num_Apps_Submitted.Value,0)))
```